# jQuery JSON get issue

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

I am trying to fetch information from a JSON file but nothing comes in the data variable. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. The JSON file is downloaded so there is no problem with me not getting anything from the server.

```
function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
    var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lng=" + position.coords.longitude + "&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function(info){
        var clouds = info.weatherObservation.clouds;
        var weather = info.weatherObservation.weatherCondition;
        var temp = info.weatherObservation.temperature;
        var humidity = info.weatherObservation.humidity;
    });
    //console.log(clouds);
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "C:" + clouds + ", W:" + weather + ", T:" + temp + ", H:" + humidity;
}
```

Appreciate all the help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: with firebug can you check the json tab on the net panel , is it giving back the same structure you are accessing.

Comment: one more suggestion anyway you are using jquery , use .html() instead of .innerhtml , you can simloy say ('#result').html(); is weatherObservation a array of objects or single object.

Comment: "nothing comes in the data variable" contradicts the statement "The JSON file is downloaded". either it comes back with something, or it doesnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try placing the code that modifies the innerHTML within the callback. Remember that JS has function scope. You can't access these variables outside. Also, those variables are set only after callback from retrieving the JSON is executed.

```
function handle_geolocation_query(position) {
    var url = "http://ws.geonames.org/findNearByWeatherJSON?lat=" + position.coords.latitude + "&lng=" + position.coords.longitude + "&callback=?";
    $.getJSON(url, function(info){
        var clouds = info.weatherObservation.clouds;
        var weather = info.weatherObservation.weatherCondition;
        var temp = info.weatherObservation.temperature;
        var humidity = info.weatherObservation.humidity;
        $('#result').html("C:" + clouds + ", W:" + weather + ", T:" + temp + ", H:" + humidity);
    });
}
```

**Edit:** Following gov's advice, you should use the jQuery API's encapsulated html() method whenever you find the need to change innerHTML.

Also, you can use:

```
console.log(info);
```

while debugging in the getJSON callback just to ensure your data is structured the way you think it is.

Comment: Oh man you saved me so much grief. I really appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @aayush , mostly as rabidfire said , it might be structure problem ,i think you are not accessing the way it is returning...?? are you getting any errors on firebug console while accessing object property's normallly if it is wrong it throws errors,

Comment: @aayush let us know once you fix the problem , just eager to know what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to do the below, i think it may be coming as array of objects

```
var clouds = info.weatherObservation.clouds;
        var weather = info[0].weatherObservation.weatherCondition;
        var temp = info[0].weatherObservation.temperature;
        var humidity = info[0].weatherObservation.humidity;
```